# Problema em trazer valor para o HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Eu possuo esse HTML e JavaScript:

```js
    var pessoa = new Person("imgs/avatarVillainInGlasses.jpg", "Rodrigo", "Gama", 29, "Masculino", "programming");

    var photoImage = document.querySelector(".photoImage");
    var name = document.querySelector(".personName");
    var age = document.querySelector(".personAge");
    var gender = document.querySelector(".personGender");
    var bio = document.querySelector(".personBio");

    photoImage.src = pessoa.photoPath;
    name.innerHTML = "Nome: " + pessoa.name.last.toUpperCase() + ", " + pessoa.name.first;
    age.innerHTML = "Idade: " + pessoa.age;
    gender.innerHTML = "Gênero: " + pessoa.gender;
    bio.innerHTML = "Descrição: " + pessoa.bio();

    function Person(photoPath, fname, lname, age, gender, interests) {
        this.photoPath = photoPath;

        this.name = {
            "first": fname,
            "last": lname
        }

        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.interests = interests;

        this.bio = function() {
            return this.name.first + " " + this.name.last + " is " + this.age + " years old. They like " + this.interests + ".";
        }

    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ptbr">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="../mainCore/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="person">
            <div class="personPhoto">
                <img class="photoImage" src="" width="180px" height="150px">
            </div>

            <div class="personInfo">

                <p class="personName">Name: </p>
                
                <p class="personAge">Age: </p>
                <p class="personGender">Gender: </p>
                <p class="personBio">Bio: </p>
            </div>
            
        </div>        
    </body>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    </html>
```

Por algum motivo que me falha a compreensão, a `var name`, que recebe o elemento de classe `personName` não consegue receber a string concatenada abaixo. Todos os outros campos estão recebendo os valores normalmente.

É apenas um projeto de estudos, não vai virar nada além de experiência para lidar com esse tipo de situação no futuro.

Comment: testei e está funcionando perfeitamente: https://jsfiddle.net/qpo1cmyg/
não está faltando a imagem no seu html?

Comment: O `<script>` deve estar dentro do `</body>` e `var pessoa = new Person()` deve estar depois de `function Person`. Já testaste isso?

Comment: Ricardo Pontual, não, pois a imagem está aparecendo pra mim quando eu testo a página. O único elemento que não é preenchido é o "personName"; EDIT: De fato, no jsFiddle está funcionando normalmente, mas quando eu testo no vsCode, está ocorrendo esse erro. EDIT2: Acabei de testar no Firefox e no Chrome. Em ambos eu tenho o mesmo problema.

Comment: Sergio, obrigado pelas dicas, mas elas não tiveram qualquer efeito;

Comment: Onde você está tentando rodar esse código? Tentei reproduzir no JSFiddle e não deu problema, então tentei reproduzir no Stack Overflow e deu problema. Por alguma razão a variável com o nome `name` causa esse bug estranho. Se você der outro nome para essa variável funciona normalmente, mas esse erro não faz muito sentido, tanto é que ele só ocorre aqui no SO.

Comment: user140828 estou rodando o código no vsCode EDIT: De fato, ao trocar o nome da variável, passou a funcionar;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse problema está sendo causado por causa da variável de nome `name`.

`name` é uma propriedade que todos os elementos do DOM possui, e quando você declara uma variável no escopo global, ela passa a ser uma propriedade do `window`.

Ao se utilizar a variável global `name`, você está acessando a propriedade `name` do `window`, mas a propriedade `name` tem uma particularidade: ela possui um `setter` - como elementos do DOM só conseguem armazenar strings na sua propriedade `name`, tudo que a propriedade `name` recebe é convertido para `string`.

Essa é a fonte do problema, ao se atribuir um valor para uma variável global de nome `name`, esse valor é convertido para `string`.